# How can I both use DISTINCT and don't care about one column's value?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO comments (root_id, r_id, user_id, comment_content)
SELECT DISTINCT root_id, r_id,user_id, comment_content FROM comments_old WHERE 1
```

Noted that I've a *unique* index on `comments(root_id, r_id, user_id)` and query above fails because `DISTINCT` cares about duplicate `comment_content` column values and it is not exist in that *unique* index. *(because its type is `TEXT` and I cannot add it into the unique index)*.

Anyway, I want to select `comment_content` but don't care about being duplicate of this column. How can I do that?

Comment: If you call `SELECT` separately will it also fail?

Comment: @ASpirin Not sure what you mean by *`SELECT` separately*? How exactly?

Comment: execute `SELECT DISTINCT root_id, r_id,user_id, comment_content FROM comments_old ` and check if it gives you an error

Comment: You can also use `insert ignore into comments(...) select root_id, ...`, without distinct. It will ignore errors, so it will skip the duplicates - which effectively means that for each unique key, it will pick any comment. The difference to what you are describing (basically a `group by`) is that it will also ignore a new row if it was already in the table - not sure if that matters or is even what you want to do.

Comment: @Solarflare Neat.. Please add it as an answer ..  I will give it an upvote

Comment: If one of the answers below has successfully addressed your problem, please consider 'accepting' it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most dialects of SQL, there's no way to express "pick a value, I don't care which". There may be a mysql dialect way but I'd expect the standard:

```
select root_id,r_id,user_id,MAX(comment_content)
from comments_old
group by root_id,r_id,user_id
```

should work. Of course, `MAX` is somewhat arbitrary, `MIN` could also be used - but you said you didn't care what value was picked.

Comment: Nice ..! You're actually abusing `group by` clause `;)`. Upvote

Comment: @stack - I'm not *abusing* `group by`. Look at your question in a different manner, and realise that effectively you're saying "I have multiple rows which share the same `root_id,r_id,user_id` values and I want those reduced to a single row in the output" and you'll realise you're describing `GROUP BY`. Or look at `DISTINCT` as always just being `GROUP BY` across all mentioned columns with no aggregates.

Comment: You're right .. Also, do you know how will `MAX` or even `MIN` treat with text values?

Comment: `MAX()` / `MIN()` will order the text alphanumerically based on the collation of the column (the equivalent of performing an `ORDER BY`) and them they will pick the last / first value based on that order.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery containing the distinct stuff, and join it to the table itself querying the comment_content values.

```sql
INSERT INTO comments (root_id, r_id, user_id, comment_content)
SELECT a.root_id, a.r_id, a.user_id, b.comment_content FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT root_id, r_id,user_id FROM comments_old WHERE 1) a, comments_old b
    WHERE a.root_id = b.root_id and a.r_id = b.r_id and a.use_id = b.user_id
```

This will give you two lines if two different comment_content values exist for the same set of keys.

Comment: I cannot analysis your query in my mind. Thank you anyway. Upvote

Comment: I basically just separated your query into one which filters the keys distinctly, and another one which queries the comment_code values based on the matching keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a slightly different approach and react to the violation of the unique key.

You can e.g. use [`insert ignore`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO comments (root_id, r_id, user_id, comment_content)
SELECT DISTINCT root_id, r_id,user_id, comment_content 
FROM comments_old WHERE 1;
```

or [`on duplicate key update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO comments (root_id, r_id, user_id, comment_content)
SELECT DISTINCT root_id, r_id,user_id, comment_content 
FROM comments_old WHERE 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE comment_content = values(comment_content);
```

`insert ignore` will also ignore other kind of errors, while `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (or `ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE`) will only skip (or handle) unique key violations. If you use `update`, it will, in this case, always take the newest value (so will overwrite existing rows).

An important difference to using `group by` is that this will also ignore a new row if a row with that key is already in the table - which is not exactly what you asked for, but may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a feature of MySQL, the following should also work*:

```
INSERT INTO comments (root_id, r_id, user_id, comment_content)
SELECT root_id, r_id, user_id, comment_content
from comments_old
group by root_id, r_id, user_id
```

This is because MySQL will allow ungrouped, unaggregated values to be included in a GROUPed select - the value selected is essentially random (within the values for the specific grouping).

.* - in versions of MySQL prior to 5.7.5, or in which ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled - see [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for further details.

Comment: Hasn't the switch default changed in more recent MySQL versions? (I.e. unaggregated columns must be specified in the GROUP BY - unless compatiblity mode is switched on.)

Comment: @jarlh - You are right - I have updated my answer accordingly. [Shakes fist at Oracle]